# Direct some posts to only appear on a specific page

Tags: posts, pages, blog

I have a blog at [JonCrowell.org](http://www.joncrowell.org).  When I add a new post, it appears on the home page. I have created a new page called "Technical Notes".  I would like to be able to choose whether a new post that I create appears on my home page (which it does right now by default), or appears under the *Technical Notes* page. Basically, some of my blog posts are general interest stuff that I want on my home page, and some are technical and esoteric and I don't want to clutter my main page with these posts. You could think of it as running a secondary blog, with all the posts appearing on a particular page. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Home Page is displayed with `index.php` or `front-page.php` in WordPress.

**PLAN B:** First of all, you have to create a category for Technical Notes page (i.e.: Category Name = "Technical Notes"). Now the plan is, all the posts, by default will be displayed on the homepage by default (as it is doing now), excluding the "Technical Notes" categorized posts, and only the Technical Notes categorized posts will be displayed on your seperate page.

On your home page (whether index.php or front-page.php), you will need to use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to query the posts, but [`exclude` the category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) "Technical Notes".

And on a page template, which will be used onto your specific page, you will need to use a `WP_Query()` to call only the posts assigned on the "Technical Notes" category.

Any query is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy and a part of WordPress. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates and http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Categories_SubPanel

Answer (score 0):

**Wp Hide Post** plugin will help you - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-post/

This plugin has ability to [hide a specific post](http://sam.azgor.com/hide-a-specific-wordpress-post-from-home-page) on "Home Page or Category Page or Archive Page" etc.

In your case create a category **Technical Notes**, add this to you nav menu or wherever you want. After installing the plugin, you'll see a new options has added at the right side when you create new post. Select hide on the front page. And also make that post under **Technical Notes** category.